# Using spring config server with git causing security group issue

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-connectors

I am now trying to set up using spring config server / spring config client and eureka server to do service discovery together. when I was using local file system to save configuration, everything is fine, but as soon as I change to gitHub to save configuration, I can not start spring config client, and I got this error message:

com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Can't get a response from http://user:{cipher}AQBdTe9vjgOqANyfi+Ke5HYmhFJnuvsGJ+8FOqLgdMdFInJkVRzy9XngylNp9KlX2lwPI13jT7ceDjBs9w4B6A15akQTHHP1q9rWwMcLtVCCKGFgvXSgQF+WWIItxBmIDGG4bSgDYZ6XQWl66T84PxjTBygErpmAjn+X2BWdtWtVmjXzpMQMaHGpiyLPoGIQYF4j9ZGpl16Jx79+j6et6LStksrT3WxQuanhZwIkqZ827+2mlUB3kd5ocW7R0vC3JMGVZlGNfqYQwJIhSJ19lrq4gxm/zbGroYonW3QSHTiRlhlvOdovEua/0dCl6+s0iEHYZCBllr7jikEWmS5Px7U2TG8/eQkjR8pUbSN6OE+OI2ZZUCNOT+mi75ZeeN1OtdQ=@localhost:8761/eureka/null

Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://user:{cipher}AQBdTe9vjgOqANyfi+Ke5HYmhFJnuvsGJ+8FOqLgdMdFInJkVRzy9XngylNp9KlX2lwPI13jT7ceDjBs9w4B6A15akQTHHP1q9rWwMcLtVCCKGFgvXSgQF+WWIItxBmIDGG4bSgDYZ6XQWl66T84PxjTBygErpmAjn+X2BWdtWtVmjXzpMQMaHGpiyLPoGIQYF4j9ZGpl16Jx79+j6et6LStksrT3WxQuanhZwIkqZ827+2mlUB3kd5ocW7R0vC3JMGVZlGNfqYQwJIhSJ19lrq4gxm/zbGroYonW3QSHTiRlhlvOdovEua/0dCl6+s0iEHYZCBllr7jikEWmS5Px7U2TG8/eQkjR8pUbSN6OE+OI2ZZUCNOT+mi75ZeeN1OtdQ=@localhost:8761/eureka/
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)

This is what I have:

1. In cofig server application.yml:

> ```
>  spring:
>       application:
>         name: spirent-config-server
>       cloud:
>         config:
>           server:
>             git:
>               uri:  https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
>               #searchPaths: foo,bar*
>
>     server:
>       port: 8888
> ```

2. in config client:

bootstrap.properties:

> ```
> spring.application.name= foo
> spring.profiles.active= development
> spring.cloud.config.uri= http://localhost:8888
> ```

and application.yml

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${host.instance.name:frank1}
    nonSecurePort: ${host.instance.port:8080}
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${host.instance.instanceid:frank_123}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

server:
  port: ${host.instance.port:8080}
```

3. Eureka Server:

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${CONFIG_SERVER_URL:http://localhost:8888}
```

From the exception, it seemed it is because discoverClient is not working, anything special for the configuration?
But if I change from gitHub to local file storage for configuration, everything is fine.

Thanks for your suggestion in advance.

Based on the spring cloud document, I am doing like this:

In application.yml of config server:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spirent-config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri:  https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
          #searchPaths: foo,bar*
encrypt:
  key: abc

server:
  port: 8888
```

In application.yml of Eureka Server:

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0

encrypt:
  key: abc
```

And in application.yml of config client:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${host.instance.name:frank1}
    nonSecurePort: ${host.instance.port:8080}
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 5 #default is 30, recommended to keep default
    metadataMap:
      #instanceId: ${host.instance.instanceid:frank_123}
      instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

server:
  port: ${host.instance.port:8080}

encrypt:
  key: abc
```

But, the problem is after I started Eureka an config server, it is fine, no exception, but after I started config client, I got this same exception:

```
Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://user:{cipher}AQBdTe9vjgOqANyfi+Ke5HYmhFJnuvsGJ+8FOqLgdMdFInJkVRzy9XngylNp9KlX2lwPI13jT7ceDjBs9w4B6A15akQTHHP1q9rWwMcLtVCCKGFgvXSgQF+WWIItxBmIDGG4bSgDYZ6XQWl66T84PxjTBygErpmAjn+X2BWdtWtVmjXzpMQMaHGpiyLPoGIQYF4j9ZGpl16Jx79+j6et6LStksrT3WxQuanhZwIkqZ827+2mlUB3kd5ocW7R0vC3JMGVZlGNfqYQwJIhSJ19lrq4gxm/zbGroYonW3QSHTiRlhlvOdovEua/0dCl6+s0iEHYZCBllr7jikEWmS5Px7U2TG8/eQkjR8pUbSN6OE+OI2ZZUCNOT+mi75ZeeN1OtdQ=@localhost:8761/eureka/
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.resource(Client.java:433)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1091)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1060)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:835)
```

Can anyone tell me where is my error? This only happened in using GIT as config server data source, but in local file data source, no error happened.

Thanks

These are my steps to try to resolve the key issues, but failed again:

1. download the "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" from Oracle, and follow instructions for installation (essentially replace the 2 policy files in the JRE lib/security directory with the ones that you downloaded).
2. Now if I run spring encrypt mysecret --key foo, it is successful, this means the JCE is installed correctly;
3. Creating a Key Store for Testing: using this:
   https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc#creating-a-key-store-for-testing
4. after updating the application.yml in my config server, the  application.yml is this:

```html
spring:
  application:
    name: spirent-config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri:  https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
          #searchPaths: foo,bar*
encrypt:
  keyStore:
    location: classpath:/server.jks
    password: letmein
    alias: abc
    secret: changeme
  key: abc

server:
  port: 8888
```

5. adding this to both eureka server and config client application.yml:

   encrypt:
     key: abc
6. Run everything:
   Result is same nasty error

So what is wrong is my testing? Thanks for your help

It is my fault:
Changing application.yml to this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
encrypt:
  failOnError: false
  keyStore:
    #location: classpath:keystore.jks
    #password: ${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD:foobar} # don't use a default in production
    #alias: test
    location: classpath:server.jks
    password: letmein
    alias: mytestkey
    secret: changeme
```

And then using this command to generate the file resolving the issue completely:

keytool -genkeypair -alias mytestkey -keyalg RSA \
  -dname "CN=Web Server,OU=Unit,O=Organization,L=City,S=State,C=US" \
  -keypass changeme -keystore server.jks -storepass letmein

Thanks

Comment: looks like the password is not being decrypted.  Are you setting `encrypt.key`?

Comment: No, not doing that. I don't see that requirements in the doc. Can you show me some doc for how to do that? Thanks @ spencergibb

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.1/spring-cloud.html#_key_management

Comment: Thank you @spencergibb, I was reading the same part in spring documentation, but after I put encrypt.key in hte applicaiton,yml, it is useless. I have attached updates in the above post, can you help to see how to fix this exception?  Thanks

Comment: Did you encrypt the values with `encrypt.key=abc`?

Comment: Are there any step by step instruction on how to do this? When I use spring encrypt mysecret --key foo, I got Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key error. This is really most confusing and difficult part in spring cloud, if  there is any guide, it will help us quite a lot.

Comment: Do you have the JCE installed as stated here? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc#encryption-and-decryption

Comment: @spencergibb, yes I just did what it is instructed in the documents, and still having exception, may you please have a look at my updated post steps and tell me which step is wrong? Thanks

Comment: So you are using https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo which has encrypted properties using a different key